# How to grant the CREATE PROCEDURE permission to dbo user in AZURE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

I have created the AZURE SQL SERVER, while creating taken "mike" user(as admin).
when I logged in from Db-visualizer and trying to create "sys.sp_addlogin" stored procedure there I'm getting following Error :
[Code: 262, SQL State: S00018]  CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.

sp_addlogin is not available on AZURE SQL so taken stored procedure code from sql server 2012 and executing in azure. more info : (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlogin-transact-sql)

How can we grant the "CREATE PROCEDURE" permission to my 'mike' dbo user.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Are you trying to add the user to a database with the sp_addlogin proc? Or create the procedure itself? Or give someone rights to create procedures?

Comment: I have my 'mike' dbo user and I'm trying to create stored procedure "sp_addlogin".

Comment: Sounds like 'mike' doesn't have permissions to create procedure. Why are you trying to add sp_addlogin anyway? Even in the article you linked it says to use [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql)

Comment: First of all you cannot create nothing in sys schema even on non AZURE SQL Server, but Azure has many restrictions and you never have a full control over the server, even over master, I think